# Facetious Sisters

Tags: riddle

Let me tell you about my sisters and I.

> I am the eldest, and in fact the first of all our siblings.
>   My next sister buys alcohol by the bottle and places them on her shelves.
>   My next sister always wraps her slim figure in the nicest of evening gowns, which she stitches herself.
>   In contrast, you can always find my next, more portly sister at the pool hall at a quarter past three every afternoon.
>   My last sister prefers playing blackjack (she sees herself in the table).

Who are we AND who are our brothers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The sisters are the vowels A, E, I, O and U. The brothers are the consonants.

I am the eldest, and in fact the first of all our siblings.

> 'A' is the first letter.

My next sister buys alcohol by the bottle and places them on her shelves.

> The letter 'E' looks like a bottle adjacent to three shelves.

My next sister always wraps her slim figure in the nicest of evening gowns, which she stitches herself.

> 'I' is a slim figure. Perhaps the horizontal lines on top and bottom resemble gowns. She stitches herself, because 'I' stands for ego.

In contrast, you can always find my next, more portly sister at the pool hall at a quarter past three every afternoon.

> 'O' is, in contrast, round and portly. It is shaped like the balls in the pool hall. 'O' is the fifteenth letter of the alphabet, so it can be seen at quarter (15) past three (A, E, I).

My last sister prefers playing blackjack (she sees herself in the table).

> 'U', shaped like blackjack table and also the 21st letter, an allusion to the fact that blackjack is also called 21.

Facetious Sisters

> The sisters appear according to their age in the word 'Facetious'.

Comment: You are correct! But your clue explanations are a bit off. Hint: each clue also, in some way, describes the letter's position in the alphabet.

Comment: @VictorHenry: Thanks, but try as I might, I am unable to justify 'evening gowns' for I and 'bottle' and 'shelves' for E.

Comment: For E: a standard sized bottle of liquor (at least in the US) is commonly referred to as a "fifth". The shelves were just a description of how a capital E looks. For I: always dressed in an evening gown ("dressed to the nines") that she stitches herself ("a stitch in time saves nine"). Also, for O, 3 in the afternoon is 1500 in military time. Good job on everything else, though!

Answer (score 0):

2 Guesses:

You Are:

> Light, and your brothers are darkness.

My next sister buys alcohol by the bottle and places them on her shelves. - **Morning sun, when preparing is done?**
My next sister always wraps her slim figure in the nicest of evening gowns, which she stitches herself.  **wrapping herself in light in the thin evening sun**
In contrast, you can always find my next, more portly sister at the pool hall at a quarter past three every afternoon. **Strong sun shining down in afternoon**
My last sister prefers playing blackjack (she sees herself in the table).  **reflection of light**

You Are:

> Wood/Trees and your brothers are humans.

My next sister buys alcohol by the bottle and places them on her shelves. - **Basic wood used for shelves**
My next sister always wraps her slim figure in the nicest of evening gowns, which she stitches herself.  **Basic tree, growing leaves/twigs?**
In contrast, you can always find my next, more portly sister at the pool hall at a quarter past three every afternoon. **Higher quality wood used for tables**
My last sister prefers playing blackjack (she sees herself in the table).  **highest quality/thick wood used for luxury tables?**
**Your brothers are the ones that change you and make you into these products?**